# How to create a graph from an incidence list with C igraph?

Tags: c, igraph

With C igraph we can create a graph from an adjacency list with `igraph_adjlist`.
It there a way to create a graph from an incidence list ?

Comment: I'm not sure why this was closed ... it's a perfectly on-topic question about using a C library. Since it was closed, I can't post an answer.

Comment: If you mean `igraph_inclist`, it makes no sense to create a graph from it because `igraph_inclist` is meaningful only relative to an existing graph. The `inclist` contains a list of edge indices for each vertex. Edge indices are used to index into an existing graph. Once cannot determine what vertices are present at the endpoints of an edge without having the graph.

Comment: I think it would be better for provide some context for this question: I assume you are trying to do this in the context of a bigger problem. What is it?

Comment: @Szabolcs, I agree that this is a perfectly on-topic question. The instructions say that the question may be improved, but I don't understand how. The question is quite clear. Indeed, as you suggest, there may be a larger question behind it. I don't know who closed it, perhaps (s)he can give a proper explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no such functionality is implemented. Feel free to open an issue at https://github.org/igraph/igraph to suggest such a feature. Alternatively, if you want to discuss it, the `igraph` project recently opened a new forum to facilitate discussions, see https://igraph.discourse.group.

Comment: Please see my comment on the question.